# Update Always Produces Table Lock

Tags: sql-server, locking, sql-server-2019

I am working on extending some legacy SQL code and am running into a problem with locking. The engine isn't working how I'd expect it to.

My understanding is that during an update, the engine will first take out a row lock then escalate to a table lock if too many rows are needed to be updated.

What I'm finding is that the engine is immediately taking out a table lock, regardless of what I try.

Setup:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.lockTest

CREATE TABLE dbo.lockTest 
(
    ID INT,
    IsActive BIT
)

INSERT INTO dbo.lockTest (ID, IsActive)
VALUES (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0)

BEGIN TRAN

    UPDATE TOP (1) dbo.lockTest
    SET IsActive = 1
    WHERE IsActive = 0

--COMMIT TRAN --Comment this out to query sys.dm_tran_locks
```

In another query window, I check out the locks that are taken out using

```
SELECT TOP 100 * 
FROM sys.dm_tran_locks AS dtl
WHERE dtl.request_session_id = 138 --use SPID from first session
```

| resource_type | resource_description | resource_associated_entity_id | request_mode | request_type | request_status | request_session_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RID | 1:971:0 | 72057594044022784 | X | LOCK | GRANT | 138 |
| PAGE | 1:971 | 72057594044022784 | IX | LOCK | GRANT | 138 |
| OBJECT |  | 709629621 | IX | LOCK | GRANT | 138 |
| OBJECT |  | 693629564 | IX | LOCK | GRANT | 138 |

This is all in SQL Server 2019 CU22 Enterprise. Why is the table lock being taken out immediately?

Comment: Please don't use images for data, use the tabular markdown provided

Comment: IX locks are intent locks. [Intent Locks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide#intent)

Comment: That's exactly it. I see that now.